# Why is the "root" logger required in my SAS log configuration file?

Tags: sas, log4j, sas-studio

I set this logs config file for retrieve SAS Studio logs:

```
Set-Content -Path "C:\SAS\ModelMgr\Lev1\Web\Common\LogConfig\SASStudio-log4j.xml" -Value @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender" name="SAS_FILE">
        <param name="append" value="true"/>
        <param name="file" value="C:/SAS/ModelMgr/Lev1/Web/Logs/SASServer1_1/SASStudioMidTier3.81.log"/>
        <layout class="com.sas.svcs.logging.CustomPatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p [%u] %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger additivity="false" name="com.sas.workflow">
        <priority value="ALL"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SAS_CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SAS_FILE"/>
    </logger>
</log4j:configuration>
"@
```

however I don't get any logs in the file.

On the contrary, when I configure my file like this :

```
    Set-Content -Path "C:\SAS\ModelMgr\Lev1\Web\Common\LogConfig\SASStudio-log4j.xml" -Value @"
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
    <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
        <appender class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender" name="SAS_FILE">
            <param name="append" value="true"/>
            <param name="file" value="C:/SAS/ModelMgr/Lev1/Web/Logs/SASServer1_1/SASStudioMidTier3.81.log"/>
            <layout class="com.sas.svcs.logging.CustomPatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p [%u] %c - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    
        <logger additivity="false" name="com.sas.workflow">
            <priority value="ALL"/>
            <appender-ref ref="SAS_CONSOLE"/>
            <appender-ref ref="SAS_FILE"/>
        </logger>

       <root>
            <priority value="DEBUG"/>
            <appender-ref ref="SAS_FILE"/>
       </root>
    </log4j:configuration>
    "@
```

According to the documentation "The root recorder is the highest level recorder and does not represent a specific message category. Recorders inherit the parameters of their higher-level (ancestor) recorders."

Therefore I do not understand why it is obliged to specify it in my case? The log "com.sas.workflow" is supposed to be inherited from him by default, isn't it?

Thanks by advance for your help